# How does one arrive at the relation of commutator $\left[M^{-i}, M^{-j}\right]$ of Lorentz generators $M^i$ in terms of the string modes $\alpha_n^i$?

Tags: operators, angular-momentum, string-theory, commutator, quantum-anomalies

I am reading the book "String theory demystified" by David McMahon.

On page 149, the author discusses the "critical dimension" for superstrings.

> the number of spacetime dimensions is easily extracted. One obtains a relation for the Lorentz generators $M^{-i}$:
> $$
> \left[M^{-i}, M^{-j}\right]=-\frac{1}{\left(p^{+}\right)^{2}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\alpha_{-n}^{i} \alpha_{n}^{j}-\alpha_{-n}^{j} \alpha_{n}^{i}\right)\left(\Delta_{n}-n\right)\tag{7.70}$$
> where
> $$\Delta_{n}=n\left(\frac{D-2}{8}\right)+\frac{1}{n}\left(2 a_{N S}-\frac{D-2}{8}\right).\tag{7.71}$$
> In order to maintain Lorentz invariance, we must have $\left[M^{-i}, M^{-j}\right]=0$. This can only be true if the first term on the right-hand side of Eq. (7.71) is $n$ and the second term vanishes. This implies that$$\begin{aligned}
> &\frac{D-2}{8}=1 \\
> &\Rightarrow D=10
> \end{aligned}\tag{7.72}$$

My questions

1. How to obtain the first equation? which seems like a kind of Lie algebra relation.
2. How does the requirement of Lorentz invariance translates to the RHS being zero?

Comment: $
P_{\pm}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1 \pm \Gamma_{11}\right)
$ 
 and $
\Gamma^{11}=\Gamma^{0} \Gamma^{1} \cdots \Gamma^{9}
$
is a 10-dimensional chirality operator. It acts on spinors $\psi$ according to
$
\Gamma^{11} \psi=\pm \psi
$
That is, states have positive or negative chirality. Weyl spinors are states with definite chirality, and states can be projected into spinors with opposite space-time chirality using the operator

Comment: Hi @Eden Zane. Do you know how to do the corresponding calculation of $\left[M^{-i}, M^{-j}\right]$ in _bosonic_ string theory?

Comment: @Qmechanic In bosonic string theory, the left hand side is just $m^2$ I think. Does $[M^{-i},M^{-j}]$ reduce to $m^2$ in the bosonic case?

Comment: I figured it out myself. It was all due to a confusion in the notation. I found the same equation( and the same discussion too) in the "superstring theory" by Greens Schwarz and Witten. Refer p.213

Comment: Should I delete this question or, let it remain here for those who come up with the same confusion later?

Comment: That is your prerogative. You may also supply an answer to help the readers.